# Can I use pybind to load an external c++ dll and call functions?

Tags: python-3.x, pybind11

I am trying to interface with a PoS terminal , which only provides a dll(c++). Can I use pybind to load the dll and call the api function by some code like :

```
import pybind11

mydll = pybind.load("/path/to/dll")

mydll.api_call(param1,param2)
```

I tried the following code in ctypes. But couldnt get the API to work or get a legible error.

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\madaapi_v1_7.dll")
mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(wintypes.DWORD), POINTER(c_byte), POINTER(c_byte),POINTER(c_byte),POINTER(c_char_p),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_byte)


bPort,dwBaudRate,bParity,bDataBits,bStopBits, inReqBuff, inReqlen, terminal_id = c_char_p(b'COM3'),wintypes.DWORD(38400),c_byte(0),c_byte(8),c_byte(1),c_char_p(b'07!'),c_int(3),c_byte()

conn = mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID(byref(bPort),byref(dwBaudRate),byref(bParity),byref(bDataBits),byref(bStopBits),byref(inReqBuff),byref(inReqlen),byref(terminal_id))
print(conn)
```

This returns the code -3 with or without the params. As per the documentation -3 refers to "Port cannot be opened". But I can see the port and open it using PySerial.

As per the dll document, these are the input data types:

```
int api_GetCOMTerminalID (BYTE bPort, DWORD dwBaudRate, BYTE bParity, BYTE bDataBits, BYTE bStopBits, unsigned char* inReqBuff, int *inReqLen, BYTE *terminalId)
```

Here is an example call:

```
api_GetCOMTerminalID (3,38400,0,8,0,”07!”,3)
```

Comment: Not as such, since pybind11 has no run-time component (that's its major selling point). But what you're asking is precisely what ctypes offers. Is the reason you don't want to use ctypes that the function has a C++ (rather than C) signature?

Comment: @WimLavrijsen I have edited the question with the code I tried in ctypes. But it didnt work.

Comment: What is the function's signature? I'd be surprised if all arguments require byref (esp. the naming of the port).

Comment: I have edited my question again with the datatypes required by the function. I dont know how to declare, assign and pass it in the call. I tried many ways and got errors and errors only.

Comment: Yes, so those `byref`s should not be there for most arguments. In the `mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID` above, remove all `byref`s except for those on `inReqlen` and `terminal_id`. Since byref passes a pointer, you are passing in more or less random values in the other cases rather then the intended ones.

Comment: I tried but no luck. All I get is a -3. Do you freelance? Can you write the wrapper for me ?

Comment: Posted. Of course, I still have this nagging feeling that you're not asking the right question. In particular to actual intent. For example, do you have the headers to that .dll? If yes, you could to the above with pybind11 (as per your original question) and create a Python extension module, just not through loading the .dll. If you have header and .dll but want ctypes-like behavior, then cffi or cppyy would be (simpler) options, too.

Comment: I do not have the header file for the dll. The PoS provider , gave a windows setup file for a GUI- to trigger the device and this dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have access to the code that you are using, but under the assumption that this signature that you posted is correct:

```
int api_GetCOMTerminalID (BYTE bPort, DWORD dwBaudRate, BYTE bParity, BYTE bDataBits, BYTE bStopBits, unsigned char* inReqBuff, int *inReqLen, BYTE *terminalId)
```

Then the following ctypes code would get all the types right:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes

BYTE      = wintypes.BYTE
DWORD     = wintypes.DWORD
c_uchar_p = POINTER(c_ubyte)
c_int_p   = POINTER(c_int)
c_BYTE_p  = POINTER(BYTE)

mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\madaapi_v1_7.dll")
mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID.argtypes = \
    (BYTE,          # BYTE bPort
     DWORD,         # DWORD dwBaudRate
     BYTE,          # BYTE bParity
     BYTE,          # BYTE bDataBits
     BYTE,          # BYTE bStopBits
     c_uchar_p,     # unsigned char* inReqBuff
     c_int_p,       # int *inReqLen
     c_BYTE_p,      # BYTE *terminalId
mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID.restype = c_int
```

And example usage:

```
bPort, dwBaudRate, bParity, bDataBits, bStopBits = \
    BYTE(3), DWORD(38400), BYTE(0), BYTE(8), BYTE(0)
inReq        = b'07!'
inReqBuff    = (c_ubyte * len(inReq))()
for i in range(len(inReq)):
    inReqBuff[i] = int(inReq[i])
inReqLen     = c_int(3)
terminal_id  = BYTE(0)

conn = mydll.api_GetCOMTerminalID(bPort, dwBaudRate, bParity, bDataBits, bStopBits,
                                  inReqBuff, byref(inReqLen), byref(terminal_id))
```

Comment: Also, can you tell  me if the API return type is char array buffer, what datatype is to be declared in func.argstype ?

Comment: For a return type, you'd set `func.restype`, not `func.argtypes`, so not really following? If return type, then `POINTER(c_ubyte)` will work. Or do you mean a char array output argument (i.e. `char**` or `unsigned char**`)?

Comment: I framed the question wrong. Thank you for the help. I understood how to use the right types in the call. I have been searching for help since past 10 days. Your solution worked.Also one more thing, after the API call the terminal_id is `c_byte(48)` , to convert to human readable, i used `terminal_id.value` and it printed `48`. I wonder if its the real terminal_id or not

Comment: There is no way I can verify directly, but yes, that's how the terminal id is supposed to be returned, so I expect it to be correct. The other reason why I'm not being more definitive, is that `BYTE` is a typedef for `unsigned char` and `48` is `'0'` in ASCII. Zero can mean "the first" (expected), but also "false" (ie. failure). Check the documentation and if there's nothing said about it, I'd open another one and see whether you get `49`. Beyond that, as I said: no way I can verify directly.